# Validations fired before form submit in mvc 5

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a Registration form whose view looks like below :

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "Please enter password.", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, "Please confirm password.", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

and the action result as below:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
  //some code here
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

The validation error messages are fired even before i click on the submit button of the form.
Should i be adding any specific code to control that?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of a simple thing:

The controller action that is displaying your view takes the model as argument. 
Why is this happening?

*The reason for this happening is because your action is taking a model => the default model binder is kicking in attempting to populate your view model and when it attempts to set a value for the Password property it will automatically add a validation error to the model state if there's no corresponding value in the request because your model property is a required attribute.*

**For example:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Process(MyViewModel model)
{
    ... if this action is called with a POST request and you have missed
        to pass a value for the "Password" form parameter 
        you will get a validation error in the corresponding partial view

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: the first time when i am loading the page, it would be httpget method. so in my get method, i am not passing any model, so the reason might not be correct. Ok please let me know how to get this fixed...

Comment: It has nothing to do with your get method, as your post method is taking the model as argument and is trying to force populate it, when no value is found, error is displayed.